# How to interface my own LLVM backend with LLVM IR

Tags: llvm-ir

I have my own linker and machine code converter.I am using my own assembly instruction for my machine.This machine is a software processor which executes machine code generated by asm to hex converter. Instead of assembly, i wan to use c language now.My question is that how to use LLVM for this purpose.
One approach could be that:
Create one parser which will read .s file (sort of asm file) generated by LLVM IR and map those instruction with my processor specific asm instruction.

I donot want to create linker and asm to machine code converter again.

Is my approach ok? or what could be the better way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The *.s file you read is not just "sort of asm", it is actually assembler that has already passed some LLVM backend, probably some X86 variant if you have not chosen a different target.

What you really want to do is to make LLVM emit assembly instructions for your own machine instead. This is what [Writing an LLVM Backend](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMBackend.html) and similar guides are about.

This is not exactly simple, but I expect that trying to translate some other machine's instruction set (let alone X86) to your own is probably even more difficult, as you would have to emulate each and every detail of a very complex machine.